# Fixed div with hovering in Safari browser

Tags: css, safari

I have fixed header in my page inside this header i have menu with property (display none) when i hover on this header (header_b) the menu will display with (display block) but it work well in all browsers except Safari browser.

```
<style>
.subnav_dd{
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-left: -13px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;     
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;
}
#nav_library:hover .subnav_dd{
    display: block;
}
</style>
  <div id="header_b" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; top:60px;">
   <div id="nav_library" class="mnb_on">
     <div id="dd_library" class="subnav_dd" align="left">Code ....... </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: which version of safari and what operation system?

Comment: Version 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)

Comment: os x el capitan version 10.11.6 (15G31)

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: subnav_dd have already border

Comment: but `#nav_library` don't (according to your css).

Comment: what is the useful for giving border to #nav_library i don't wont to show it i want to show .subnav_dd

Comment: As explained in my answer - if `#nav_library` doesn't have width/height - you can't `hover` it. When added the border I just made that element "size"-able (so you can `hover` it). Same works with width/height (or add some content to that element).

Answer (score 0):

In your example - the `#nav_library` element has no width/height/content, so you can't really `hover` it (there is no available area to hover).

Note in this example that you can't `hover` the `#nav_library` element (in any browser):

```css
.subnav_dd{
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-left: -13px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;     
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;
}
#nav_library:hover .subnav_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_b" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; z-index: 999; top:60px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="nav_library" class="mnb_on">
    <div id="dd_library" class="subnav_dd" align="left">Code ....... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While this example show that you can (I added a border to make the element take area on the screen):

```css
.subnav_dd{
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-left: -13px;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;     
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #CCC;
}
#nav_library {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#nav_library:hover .subnav_dd{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_b" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; z-index: 999; top:60px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div id="nav_library" class="mnb_on">
    <div id="dd_library" class="subnav_dd" align="left">Code ....... </div>
  </div>
</div>
```